# How to simplify this Boolean expression

Tags: boolean-algebra

F=(A+B+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C')

I used sop method and I am left with A+BC', so the above expression should leave me with (A+B)(A+C'). Iam not able to get to this answer. Help is appreciated.

Comment: Sorry my mistake.  Thanks for pointing it out.I corrected the same.

Comment: No worries. $\;\!$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\begin{align} F & =(\color{blue}{A+B}+\color{red}{C})(\color{blue}{A+B}+\color{red}{C'})(A+B'+C')\tag{1}\\ 
& = ((\color{blue}{A+B})+(\color{red}{CC'}))(A + B' + C')\tag{2}\\ 
& =(\color{green}{A}+B)(\color{green}{A}+B'+C')\tag{3}\\ 
& = \color{green}{A}+(B(B'+C'))\tag{4} \\ 
& = A+ \underbrace{BB'}_{\large = \, 0} + BC' \tag{5}\\ 
& = A + BC' \tag{6 SOP} \\ 
& = (A+B)(A+C')\tag{7 POS}
\end{align}$$

Comment: I don't get the step from (1) to (2).

Comment: It's the distributive law, "in reverse" $ (P + Q) (P + Q') = P + QQ'$. Distributing $P + QQ'$ gives us back $(P + Q)(P + Q')$. In this problem, $P = A+B$. Perhaps it is easier to see this in propositional logic. $$(P\lor Q) \land (P \lor Q') = P \lor (Q \land \lnot Q)$$

Comment: Yep, got it. $\;\!$

Comment: You're welcome, turtle!

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{align}
F & =(A+B+C)(A+B+C')(A+B'+C') 
\\ & = (A+B+C)\Bigl((A+B+C')(A+B+C')\Bigr)(A+B'+C') 
\\ & = \Bigl((A+B+C)(A+B+C')\Bigr)\Bigl((A+B+C')(A+B'+C')\Bigr) 
\\ & = (A+B)(A+C')
\\ & = A+AB+AC'+BC' 
\\ & = A + BC'
\end{align}$